# Is the verb "fall" used correctly?

Tags: meaning

> Sales appear to be down in October compared to August and September.
>   The picture comes from a business that has sales activity only on
>   days when the finan­cial markets are open. Because of the way that
>   weekends and holidays fell in 2003, October had fewer trading days
>   than August and September.

I'm a little bit confused by the last sentence. I understand the meaning which is: "The number of weekends and holiday days fell...". Is the last sentence written properly? Would you write it too or it does not simply sound right to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is written properly.

'Fall' is used in this way to mean 'day or date of occurrence'. We could say, for example,"My birthday fell on a Wednesday this year", or ask "What date does Easter fall on this year?"

This reflects the 'beyond control' nature of time. Probably, that particular October had 5 weekends as well as the holidays, which is beyond the control of the traders.